# Finding the date in a year if i have a given number in Python

Tags: python, date, datetime

I have two integers, one represents the year and one is the number of the day in that year.
Example: 2004 and 68

I have to find a way to turn the 68 into 8.03.2004

I just started using **Python** and I don't really know how to use the datetime command. If anyone could give me some tips it would be nice ;)

Comment: Your first port of call should be the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) which includes examples for many different uses of the `datetime` module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `datetime.timedelta` to advance from the beggining of year:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
# we start from day 1, not day 0, so we need to substract one day
print(datetime(2004, 1, 1) + timedelta(days=68 - 1))
# 2004-03-08 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to calculate it:

```
import datetime
year = 2004
day_of_year = 68
print datetime.date(year,1,1) + datetime.timedelta(days=day_of_year-1)
```